# Position tooltip in center of bar

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Can't find a way to position tooltip in center of bar like this (yeah, I know it is not exactly in center on this screenshot, but still):

[image]

If I use [`custom`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-model) tooltip option, I can get only `x` and `y` positions of a caret on top of a bar. But can't get height/width of a bar.

Here is a part of an options object that I pass to Chart constructor:

```
const options = {
  tooltips: {
    enabled: false,
    custom: (tooltip) => {
      // Retrieving valuable props from tooltip (caretX, caretY)
      // and creating custom tooltip that is positioned
      // on top of a bar
    }
  }
  // other options
}

const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data,
  options
})
```

Comment: @ℊααnd Yes, height/width of a bar on hover + top left coordinates of this bar

Comment: Do you have a sample/some code that we can look at?

Comment: @Trevor Updated my question

Comment: You have `xAlign` and `yAlign` properties for custom tooltip, but still- please preape some dome so we'll be able to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you may already know, to position a custom tooltip at the center of a bar, you might need some of it­*'s* *(bar)* properties, such as - width, height, top and left position. But unfortunately, there is no straight-forward way of getting these properties, rather you need to calculate them yourself.

To obtain / calculate those properties, you can use the following function *(can be named anything)*, which will return an object containing all these (width, height, top, left) properties of a particular bar, when hovered over.

```
function getBAR(chart) {
   const dataPoints = tooltipModel.dataPoints,
         datasetIndex = chart.data.datasets.length - 1,
         datasetMeta = chart.getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex),
         scaleBottom = chart.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom,
         bar = datasetMeta.data[dataPoints[0].index]._model,
         canvasPosition = chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
         paddingLeft = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(chart.canvas).paddingLeft),
         paddingTop = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(chart.canvas).paddingTop),
         scrollLeft = document.body.scrollLeft,
         scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;

   return {
      top: bar.y + canvasPosition.top + paddingTop + scrollTop,
      left: bar.x - (bar.width / 2) + canvasPosition.left + paddingLeft + scrollLeft,
      width: bar.width,
      height: scaleBottom - bar.y
   }
}
```

#### Calculate Center Position

After retrieving the required properties, you can calculate center position of a bar as such :

> =  - + (- / )

­

> =  - + (- / )

then, create your custom tooltip element and position it accordingly.

---

#### ᴘʀᴇᴠɪᴇᴡ

[image: bar-chart]

#### [ʟɪᴠᴇ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ](https://jsfiddle.net/j43eg3rr/show/) ⧩

```js
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Revenue',
         data: [4, 2, 3, 3],
         backgroundColor: '#2d4e6d'
      }, {
         label: 'Expenses',
         data: [3, 3.5, 4, 1],
         backgroundColor: '#c06526'
      }, {
         label: 'Profit',
         data: [3, 2.5, 4, 2],
         backgroundColor: '#e0ecf0'
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            stacked: true
         }],
         yAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      },
      tooltips: {
         enabled: false,
         custom: function(tooltipModel) {
         /*** jQuery IS USED FOR SIMPLICITY ***/
         
            /* TOOLTIP & CARET ELEMENT */
            let tooltip = $('#tooltip');
            let tooltipCaret = $('#tooltip-caret');

            /* CREATE TOOLTIP & CARET ELEMENT AT FIRST RENDER */
            if (!tooltip.length && !tooltipCaret.length) {
               tooltip = $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'tooltip');
               tooltipCaret = $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'tooltip-caret');
               $('body').append(tooltip, tooltipCaret);
            }

            /* HIDE IF NO TOOLTIP */
            if (!tooltipModel.opacity) {
               tooltip.hide();
               tooltipCaret.hide();
               return;
            }

            /* GET BAR PROPS (width, height, top, left) */
            const barWidth = getBAR(this._chart).width,
                  barHeight = getBAR(this._chart).height,
                  barTop = getBAR(this._chart).top,
                  barLeft = getBAR(this._chart).left;

            /* SET STYLE FOR TOOLTIP 
             (these can also be set in separate css file) */
            tooltip.css({
               "display": "inline-block",
               "position": "absolute",
               "color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
               "background": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)",
               "padding": "5px",
               "font": "12px Arial",
               "border-radius": "3px",
               "white-space": "nowrap",
               "pointerEvents": "none"
            });

            /* SET STYLE FOR TOOLTIP CARET 
             (these can also be set in separate css file) */
            tooltipCaret.css({
               "display": "block",
               "position": "absolute",
               "width": 0,
               "pointerEvents": "none",
               "border-style": "solid",
               "border-width": "8px 10px 8px 0",
               "border-color": "transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) transparent transparent"
            });

            /* ADD CONTENT IN TOOLTIP */
            tooltip.text('ChartJS');
            tooltip.append('<br><div class="color-box"></div><label style="display: block; margin: -16px 0 0 16px;"> Custom Tooltip<label>');

            /* POSITION TOOLTIP & CARET
            (position should be set after tooltip & caret is rendered) */
            const centerX = barLeft + (barWidth / 2),
                  centerY = barTop + (barHeight / 2)
            
            tooltip.css({
               "top": centerY - (tooltip.outerHeight() / 2) + 'px',
               "left": centerX + tooltipCaret.outerWidth() + 'px'
            });
            tooltipCaret.css({
               "top": centerY - (tooltipCaret.outerHeight() / 2) + 'px',
               "left": centerX + 'px'
            });

            /* FUNCTION TO GET BAR PROPS */
            function getBAR(chart) {
               const dataPoints = tooltipModel.dataPoints,
                     datasetIndex = chart.data.datasets.length - 1,
                     datasetMeta = chart.getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex),
                     scaleBottom = chart.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom,
                     bar = datasetMeta.data[dataPoints[0].index]._model,
                     canvasPosition = chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
                     paddingLeft = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(chart.canvas).paddingLeft),
                     paddingTop = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(chart.canvas).paddingTop),
                     scrollLeft = document.body.scrollLeft,
                     scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;

               return {
                  top: bar.y + canvasPosition.top + paddingTop + scrollTop,
                  left: bar.x - (bar.width / 2) + canvasPosition.left + paddingLeft + scrollLeft,
                  width: bar.width,
                  height: scaleBottom - bar.y
               }
            }

         }
      }
   }
});
```

```css
.color-box{width:12px;height:12px;background:#c06526;display:inline-block;margin-top:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

### UPDATE

IF you wish to position tooltip at the center of each bar segment then, use the following function :

```
function getBARSegment(chart) {
   const dataPoints = tooltipModel.dataPoints,
         bar = chart.active[dataPoints[0].datasetIndex]._model,
         canvasPosition = chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
         paddingLeft = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(chart.canvas).paddingLeft),
         paddingTop = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(chart.canvas).paddingTop),
         scrollLeft = document.body.scrollLeft,
         scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;

   return {
      top: bar.y + canvasPosition.top + paddingTop + scrollTop,
      left: bar.x - (bar.width / 2) + canvasPosition.left + paddingLeft + scrollLeft,
      width: bar.width,
      height: bar.base - bar.y
   }
}
```

---

#### ᴘʀᴇᴠɪᴇᴡ

[image: bar-chart]

#### [ʟɪᴠᴇ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ](https://jsfiddle.net/55uyhcse/show/) ⧩

```js
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Revenue',
         data: [4, 2, 3, 3],
         backgroundColor: '#2d4e6d'
      }, {
         label: 'Expenses',
         data: [3, 3.5, 4, 1],
         backgroundColor: '#c06526'
      }, {
         label: 'Profit',
         data: [3, 2.5, 4, 2],
         backgroundColor: '#e0ecf0'
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            stacked: true
         }],
         yAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      },
      tooltips: {
         enabled: false,
         custom: function(tooltipModel) {
            /*** jQuery IS USED FOR SIMPLICITY ***/

            /* TOOLTIP & CARET ELEMENT */
            let tooltip = $('#tooltip');
            let tooltipCaret = $('#tooltip-caret');

            /* CREATE TOOLTIP & CARET ELEMENT AT FIRST RENDER */
            if (!tooltip.length && !tooltipCaret.length) {
               tooltip = $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'tooltip');
               tooltipCaret = $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'tooltip-caret');
               $('body').append(tooltip, tooltipCaret);
            }

            /* HIDE IF NO TOOLTIP */
            if (!tooltipModel.opacity) {
               tooltip.hide();
               tooltipCaret.hide();
               return;
            }

            /* GET BAR PROPS (width, height, top, left) */
            const barWidth = getBARSegment(this._chart).width,
                  barHeight = getBARSegment(this._chart).height,
                  barTop = getBARSegment(this._chart).top,
                  barLeft = getBARSegment(this._chart).left;

            /* SET STYLE FOR TOOLTIP 
             (these can also be set in separate css file) */
            tooltip.css({
               "display": "inline-block",
               "position": "absolute",
               "color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
               "background": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)",
               "padding": "5px",
               "font": "12px Arial",
               "border-radius": "3px",
               "white-space": "nowrap",
               "pointerEvents": "none"
            });

            /* SET STYLE FOR TOOLTIP CARET 
             (these can also be set in separate css file) */
            tooltipCaret.css({
               "display": "block",
               "position": "absolute",
               "width": 0,
               "pointerEvents": "none",
               "border-style": "solid",
               "border-width": "8px 10px 8px 0",
               "border-color": "transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) transparent transparent"
            });

            /* ADD CONTENT IN TOOLTIP */
            tooltip.text('ChartJS');
            tooltip.append('<br><div class="color-box"></div><label style="display: block; margin: -16px 0 0 16px;"> Custom Tooltip<label>');

            /* POSITION TOOLTIP & CARET
            (position should be set after tooltip & caret is rendered) */
            const centerX = barLeft + (barWidth / 2),
                  centerY = barTop + (barHeight / 2)

            tooltip.css({
               "top": centerY - (tooltip.outerHeight() / 2) + 'px',
               "left": centerX + tooltipCaret.outerWidth() + 'px'
            });
            tooltipCaret.css({
               "top": centerY - (tooltipCaret.outerHeight() / 2) + 'px',
               "left": centerX + 'px'
            });

            /* FUNCTION TO GET BAR PROPS */
            function getBARSegment(chart) {
               const dataPoints = tooltipModel.dataPoints,
                     bar = chart.active[dataPoints[0].datasetIndex]._model,
                     canvasPosition = chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
                     paddingLeft = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(chart.canvas).paddingLeft),
                     paddingTop = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(chart.canvas).paddingTop),
                     scrollLeft = document.body.scrollLeft,
                     scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;

               return {
                  top: bar.y + canvasPosition.top + paddingTop + scrollTop,
                  left: bar.x - (bar.width / 2) + canvasPosition.left + paddingLeft + scrollLeft,
                  width: bar.width,
                  height: bar.base - bar.y
               }
            }

         }
      }
   }
});
```

```css
.color-box{width:12px;height:12px;background:#c06526;display:inline-block;margin-top:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have some suggestions to your answer if you don't mind. **1)** Scale id can be dynamic, so instead of `scaleBottom = chart.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom` let's use `bar.base`. **2)** Custom tooltip can be appended not only in `body`, so position calculations may vary. Let's simplify `getBAR` method: we can remove `canvasPosition`, `paddingLeft` and etc. So `getBAR` will return bar position relative to `chart` itself. Further position calculations depends on where user will place tooltip in DOM (so we still have it in your *Live examples*).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, we can't use `bar.base` there. So it can be like this: `const yAxesId = chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].id` and then `chart.scales[yAxesId].bottom`. And I think in this case it will be better to rename the second `getBar` function to `getBarSegment`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Actually **1.** the aim of using `chart.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom` is to get the bottom position of the scale, so we can subtract bar-top from it and get the bar-height, and it really doesn't matter whether the scale id is dynamic or not, all y-axis scale's bottom position will be the same. **2.** `canvasPosition`, `paddingLeft` etc. don't depend on `body`. Here we're trying to get the center position of a bar and it has nothing to do with where we append the tooltip and position it, later in time. (**tip:** it's always wise to append the tooltip in `body`)

Comment: and obviously, one can tweak the functions according to their need if they want *(just tried to give an idea what they might have to consider)*.

Answer (score 4):

For **Chartjs 3+** (tested in 3.5.1)

```js
Chart.Tooltip.positioners.center = function (elements, eventPosition) {
    if(elements.length){ // to prevent errors in the console
        const { x, y, base } = elements[0].element; // _model doesn't exist anymore
        const height = !base ? 0 : base - y;// so it doesn't break in combo graphs like lines + bars
        return { x, y: y + (height / 2) };
    }
    return false; // without this it gets stuck in the last active tooltip 
};
```

Set this custom "center" position in **options.plugins.tooltip.position** instead of the previous **options.tooltips.position**

**Chartjs 2.8** allows you to add custom position modes for tooltips. With this you can create a center position option:

```js
Chart.Tooltip.positioners.center = function (elements) {
    const { x, y, base } = elements[0]._model;
    const height = base - y;
    return { x, y: y + (height / 2) };
};
```

See fiddle for working example: https://jsfiddle.net/astroash/wk5y0fqd/36/

Comment: This is the ideal solution, should be the selected answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use values from the `datasets` to workout the relative height of the item being hovered over and adjust the CSS accordingly.

The following is close to the centre, but is not the exact centre. My calculations need correcting if you want exactness.

Inside the custom tooltip function include the following:

```
// find relative proportion
var dataIndex = tooltip.dataPoints[0].index;
var datasetIndex = tooltip.dataPoints[0].datasetIndex;
var totalHeight = 0;

var thisHeight = this._chart.config.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[dataIndex];

for (var i = 0; i <= datasetIndex; i++)
{
  totalHeight += this._chart.config.data.datasets[i].data[dataIndex];
}

var positionY = this._chart.canvas.offsetTop;
var positionX = this._chart.canvas.offsetLeft;
var chartHeight = this._chart.canvas.scrollHeight;
var tooltipHalfHeight = tooltip.height / 2;

// Display, position, and set styles for font
tooltipEl.style.left = positionX + tooltip.caretX + 'px';
tooltipEl.style.top = tooltip.caretY + ((chartHeight - tooltip.caretY - positionY) * (thisHeight / totalHeight / 2)) - tooltipHalfHeight + 'px';
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
  canvas{
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
  }
  #chartjs-tooltip {
   opacity: 1;
   position: absolute;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
   color: white;
   border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
   transition: all .1s ease;
   pointer-events: none;
   /*-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
   transform: translate(-50%, 0);*/
  }
  .chartjs-tooltip-key {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   margin-right: 10px;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chartjs-tooltip">
   <table></table>
</div>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

  <script>
var customTooltips = function(tooltip) {
   // Tooltip Element
   var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');
   if (!tooltipEl) {
    tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
    tooltipEl.id = 'chartjs-tooltip';
    tooltipEl.innerHTML = "<table></table>"
    this._chart.canvas.parentNode.appendChild(tooltipEl);
   }
   // Hide if no tooltip
   if (tooltip.opacity === 0) {
    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
    return;
   }
   // Set caret Position
   tooltipEl.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
   if (tooltip.yAlign) {
    tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltip.yAlign);
   } else {
    tooltipEl.classList.add('no-transform');
   }
   function getBody(bodyItem) {
    return bodyItem.lines;
   }
   // Set Text
   if (tooltip.body) {
    var titleLines = tooltip.title || [];
    var bodyLines = tooltip.body.map(getBody);
    var innerHtml = '<thead>';
    titleLines.forEach(function(title) {
     innerHtml += '<tr><th>' + title + '</th></tr>';
    });
    innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';
    bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
     var colors = tooltip.labelColors[i];
     var style = 'background:' + colors.backgroundColor;
     style += '; border-color:' + colors.borderColor;
     style += '; border-width: 2px'; 
     var span = '<span class="chartjs-tooltip-key" style="' + style + '"></span>';
     innerHtml += '<tr><td>' + span + body + '</td></tr>';
    });
    innerHtml += '</tbody>';
    var tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
    tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
   }
   
   // find relative proportion
   var dataIndex = tooltip.dataPoints[0].index;
   var datasetIndex = tooltip.dataPoints[0].datasetIndex;
   var totalHeight = 0;
   
   var thisHeight = this._chart.config.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[dataIndex];
   
   for (var i = 0; i <= datasetIndex; i++)
   {
       totalHeight += this._chart.config.data.datasets[i].data[dataIndex];
   }

   var positionY = this._chart.canvas.offsetTop;
   var positionX = this._chart.canvas.offsetLeft;
   var chartHeight = this._chart.canvas.scrollHeight;
   var tooltipHalfHeight = tooltip.height / 2;
   
   // Display, position, and set styles for font
   tooltipEl.style.opacity = 1;
   tooltipEl.style.left = positionX + tooltip.caretX + 'px';
   tooltipEl.style.top = tooltip.caretY + ((chartHeight - tooltip.caretY - positionY) * (thisHeight / totalHeight / 2)) - tooltipHalfHeight + 'px';
   tooltipEl.style.fontFamily = tooltip._fontFamily;
   tooltipEl.style.fontSize = tooltip.fontSize;
   tooltipEl.style.fontStyle = tooltip._fontStyle;
   tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltip.yPadding + 'px ' + tooltip.xPadding + 'px';
  };
  
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ["This", "That", "Something else", "Important thing", "Oh really?", "What!!"],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 1
        }, {
          data: [2, 5, 13, 5, 3, 4],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            stacked: true
          }]
        },
        tooltips: {
          enabled: false,
          custom: customTooltips,
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/f0EqpYe6zJMyIDxY4Xg9?p=preview