# Adding caret/arrow to a Chart.js custom html tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to add a caret to a custom html tooltip. Following the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html?h=tooltip%20c#external-custom-tooltips), this example is given:

```
// Set caret Position
tooltipEl.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
if (tooltipModel.yAlign) {
    tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltipModel.yAlign);
} else {
    tooltipEl.classList.add('no-transform');
}
```

From where those classes are coming from?
I couldn't find a working demo with html tooltip and a caret.

Thanks

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45489192) will somewhat help you understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with *chart.js* but my best guess is that those are the default pie chart classes (can't really tell for other chart types) that automatically draw the caret on the tooltip depending on the current y-axis position of the slice in the chart, now if you are using any other chart type with a custom HTML tooltip, you must declare in your style definition the class or classes that apply to your tooltip for the caret to be drawn for it for example:

```
  #chartjs-tooltip {
       opacity: 1;
       position: absolute;
       background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
       color: white;
       padding: 3px;
       border-radius: 3px;
       -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
       transition: all .1s ease;
       pointer-events: none;
       -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
       transform: translate(-50%, 0);
   }
   #chartjs-tooltip.below {
       -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
       transform: translate(-50%, 0);
   }
   #chartjs-tooltip.below:before {
       border: solid;
       border-color: #111 transparent;
       border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) transparent;
       border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
       bottom: 1em;
       content:"";
       display: block;
       left: 50%;
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 99;
       -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
       transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
   }
   #chartjs-tooltip.above {
       -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
       transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
   }
   #chartjs-tooltip.above:before {
       border: solid;
       border-color: #111 transparent;
       border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) transparent;
       border-width: 8px 8px 0 8px;
       bottom: 1em;
       content:"";
       display: block;
       left: 50%;
       top: 100%;
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 99;
       -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
       transform: translate(-50%, 0);
   }
```